# Combobox that cannot show entire string only shows the end

Tags: vba, combobox

I have been unable to find a solution for this anywhere. I have a combobox in vba filled with group names. Most of the names are longer than the groupbox text area, and when a new group is selected from the dropdown, it only shows the end. I would like it to show the beginning of the text. I have tried  combobox.select(index) in a selection changed event handler. Please advise the best way to start at the beginning when the selection is changed.

EDIT: I have not found a solution still to this. I am attaching a picture of the combobox and what the issue is. As you can see, it is showing the end of the phrase, rather than the start.

[image]